# How do I find out a list of RPMs installed using "--force" option?

Tags: linux, rpm, rhel-5

I'm just wondering if there is an easy way I can generate a list of RPM packages which have been forcefully installed on the system (got a couple of servers transitioned).

All servers are RedHat-5 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Perhaps you want `package-cleanup --problems` instead.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (package-cleanup --problems). Thank you so very much!